# BlackBerry ContentHandler SEND invoked directly from camera - where is data?

Tags: java, blackberry, camera

I've got a UiApp that's going to respond to ContentHandler SEND events like the SendMediaDemo, which is in the samples tree and documented here:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Create_BB_app_plays_media_from_a_user_734821_11.jsp

Their code deals with getting data by opening up the file URL with getURL() and peeling the data out. That works for me too, when the user selects a picture from the media gallery and uses the "Send to [my app]" menu option.

However, in the bb camera app, when the user takes a new picture they are given a menu with the "send to..." targets on it. When the user sends from there, before explicitly saving the picture to disk, the invocation getURL() has the value "file://nullnullnull"

The Invocation API includes the method byte[] getData(), but that's returning an array with length zero.

So where is the data?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares, it looks like it's a known RIM bug.

https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/JAVAAPI-963

You have to jump through all their registration hoops to look at that link, but it's this exact issue.